# I have a template that uses tcolorbox, which requires verbatim package, how can I install it?

Tags: packages, miktex, tcolorbox, verbatim

I use MikTex on Windows and I can't find the verbatim package anywhere. Apparently, it is not distributed anymore? I can't just try to rebuild the template.

In this template, there is a class which defines commands etc. It uses tcolorbox.
It would be great if someone could help me out and tell me how to get verbatim. I suppose it would be quite a challenge to avoid the problem and use a different package.
Obviously I've tried googling and MikTex does not offer verbatim either.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This package is part of the basic MiKTeX distribution, in `latex-tools`.

Comment: If you search for packages on CTAN they will tell you the names used by MikTeX and TeXLive.

Comment: verbatim is part of the required latex-tools bundle distributed by the latex team. If you have latex at all then you should have it installed already.